# Alternative to boost::lexical_cast

Tags: c++

I'm taking a part in a challenge, and just to cut to the point, in one of places in my program I need to convert string to an integer. I've tried boost::lexical_cast but unfortunatelly it is sooo sloowwww. I suppose because all of the checks it performs. What I need is something that would perform this conversion without any checks (I know that there will be valid numbers stored as strings). By the way using stringstream in the naive way:

```
stringstream interpreter;
interpreter << str;
interpreter >> number;
```

is even slower than boost::lexical_cast.
Is atoi the only alternative?

Comment: In some challenges I've heard comments from insane people writing their own implementations of `strtoul` etc to get some extra milliseconds... if you know that your input is well-formed, you can get away with fewer checks and cases...

Comment: Don't forget about stoi.  It's new in C++11.  It's not going to be faster than atoi, or the naive method, but by my tests it's the fastest safe method.

Answer (score 19):

You could do it using `sscanf` but I suspect it's slower than `atoi` as it handles locales.

You'll definitely be interested in reading this [C++ Convert String to Int Speed](http://tinodidriksen.com/2010/02/16/cpp-convert-string-to-int-speed/) benchmark that features a naive implementation that is faster than `atoi`.

EDIT: Another post comparing different string to int implementations: [C++ String to Int](http://www.kumobius.com/2013/08/c-string-to-int/).

Comment: @Gregory, it is very interesting, and somehow dissapointing. Dissapointing from the point that there is (in the competition) C# project, and if I compare just reading file, then C++ is about 3x faster, but when I start converting to int (the same algorithm as the C# project) using std facilities or boost, then C++ goes down and is twice slower, and they are using parseInt (which is their std).

Comment: @Gregor, just to clarify something, I've already did one project which works about 3x faster then the fastest C# project, but in order to achieve that I had to use just speed deamons (pointers and arrays) otherwise there was just no way to beat them. Not by using std facilities nor boost.

Comment: as a side note, if you're really after performance in this challenge; avoid C++ iostreams and use C streams (`FILE*`)

Comment: @Gregory Pakosz thanks for the C streams.I really have to say that as much as I love C++ after the experience with this challenge I see that C# isn't really slow, basically unless using deamons there is no chance to beat it using just std facilities or boost. Quite surprising.

Comment: likely what're you're referring to when saying "using just std facilities or boost" involves code written in a way that makes use lots of temporaries and copies

Comment: @Gregory, I'm not sure about it, every operation (read, multiply and write is done really just the bare minimum). I am aware of temporaries and I don't think there are any really (any surplus ofcourse)

Comment: @Gregory: I must admit I find it sad that the fastest method is to recode it :(

Comment: @smallB There's always Boost.Spirit, which is stunningly quick on parsing and printing numbers.

Answer (score 12):

I can recommend Boost Spirit (parse with Qi):

1. some benchmarks

   - https://cppsoup.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/boost-spirit-v2-x-versus-cs-atoi/
   - karma benchmark in documentation
2. See also my other answer [atoi on a character array with lots of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317890/atoi-on-a-character-array-with-lots-of-integers/6317971#6317971)
3. some sample uses:

.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;


const char *demo1 = "1234";
const char *demo2 = "1234,2345,-777,-888";
const char *demo3 = " 1234 , 2345 , -777, -888  ";

void do_demo1()
{
    const char *begin = demo1;
    const char *iter  = begin;
    const char *end   = demo1+strlen(demo1);
    int result;

    if (qi::parse(iter, end, qi::int_, result))
        std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "parse failed at #" << (iter - begin) << ": " << std::string(iter, end) << std::endl;

    //// to allow for spaces, use phrase_parse instead of parse
    // if (qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, qi::int_, qi::space, result)
            //// ... etc
}

void do_demo2()
{
    const char *begin = demo2;
    const char *iter  = begin;
    const char *end   = demo2+strlen(demo2);
    std::vector<int> results;

    if (qi::parse(iter, end, qi::int_ % ',', results))
         std::cout << "results = " << results.size() << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "parse failed at #" << (iter - begin) << ": " << std::string(iter, end) << std::endl;
}

void do_demo3()
{
    const char *begin = demo3;
    const char *iter  = begin;
    const char *end   = demo3+strlen(demo3);
    std::vector<int> results;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, qi::int_ % ',', qi::space, results))
         std::cout << "results = " << results.size() << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "parse failed at #" << (iter - begin) << ": " << std::string(iter, end) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    do_demo1();
    do_demo2();
    do_demo3();
    return 0;
}
```

### Other

Be sure to look at binary (de)serialization IFF you can dictate the stream (text) format. See my recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317890/atoi-on-a-character-array-with-lots-of-integers/6317971#6317971) for a comparison of methods when aimed at serializing/deserializing:

- STL (unadorned ANSI C++98 standard library)
- Boost Spirit (above)
- Boost Serialization

That post includes benchmarks

Comment: ["With constexpr format string compilation fmt::format/fmt::compile is about as fast on integer formatting as Karma generate on their own benchmark and ~3.5x faster than printf. There is still room for improvement though"](https://twitter.com/vzverovich/status/1168545905504485380)

Answer (score 8):

For the Google Summer of Code I'm working on a new Boost library to tackle this; boost::coerce which can be found over [here](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/coerce/). The backend builds upon boost::spirit providing you all of its advantages (speed in particular) with a much simpler interface:

```
int i = boost::coerce::as<int>("23");
```

or

```
std::string s = boost::coerce::as<std::string>(23);
```

Note that it is still a work in progress, but should be sufficiently stable in practice. If any problems arise, please let me know.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you comment on why you don't just modify lexical_cast to be faster, so that existing users will benefit, rather than making yet another interface?

Comment: @john-zwinck There is no way to reproduce the exact behavior of boost::lexical_cast with boost::spirit since it has quirks inherited from the stringstream backend (which wouldn't even be desirable to reproduce in some cases) and it misses features such as locale support. In return I'm implementing features as coerce::as<int>("0x23", tag::hex) which I believe are very useful.

Comment: All right.  While we're at it, I have to say it would be nice if you supported base-36 as well.  :)

Comment: @john-zwinck Sure, a generic tag::base(x) is planned, though I still have to figure out how to implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

[strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) can be a better atoi (specifically w.r.t. error handling), and will be faster than lexical_cast.

Answer (score 1):

The atoi/itoa functions are usually faster, as is sscanf().

All these are from the c runtime, but they should work well for you.

Comment: @Cubbi: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/. The opposite of atoi, i.e. integer to string. (not relly relevant here.. )

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't need to do any checks, the quickest way could be to convert the string yourself. I mean to code something like this:

```
int integer_from(string s)
{
  int n = 0;
  for (string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++)
  {
    n = 10*n + (*it) - '0';
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: yes, I did that in my previous project when I didn't constrained myself to use only things available in std. This time I'm trying to do the same work but using only libraries which are publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

how about using stoi(). I am sure that it must be fast enough to satisfy your needs.