# stoi - issue with design

Tags: c++

I've asked in one of [my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404079/alternative-to-boostlexical-cast) a question about alternative to `boost::lexical_cast` and amongst many replies I've got one suggestion `stoi` as a viable alternative.
I've decided to test it and to my surprise as a second argument to this function (argument describing size) is a pointer to `size_t` type, not actual `size_t` type. Is there any logical explanation for that and in what way it is better to have a pointer to actual object than object itself (just in this particular case when size is concerned and I wouldn't instinctively assign size with pointer)?

Link to stoi doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404860.aspx

Comment: Please supply a link to documentation for `stoi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a way of having *optional* arguments. Basically, if you are interested in knowing which is the first character that was not converted into the number. If you are not really interested in that result, you can pass nullptr.

> §21.5 [string.conversions]/1 [...] If the function does not throw an exception and idx != 0, the function stores in *idx the index of the first unconverted element of str.

This is meant to be used as:

```
int main() {
   std::string two{"2 and more contents"};
   // I don't care, just want a number:
   int i = std::stoi( two, 0, 10 );            // base = 0

   std::size_t first_not_converted;
   int i = std::stoi( two, &first_not_converted, 10 );

   std::cout << "Unconverted string is: " << two.substr( first_not_converted ) << std::endl;
}
```

By using a pointer you can make the argument really optional, if it was an out parameter, but required a reference would be used, but that would require user code to create the variable *always* regardless of whether they are interested in the value or not, so it would not be really optional.

Comment: ok I get it. Still, can't really see much use of it. When would this function not throw and in the same time didn't convert all characters?

Comment: @smallB: For the input `"10B"`, `stoi` will return `10` and set the pointer passed to `2` to indicate that you can now read from `"B"` onward to get the rest of the string.

Comment: @Matthieu after your comment +1, I actually think that this is freaking clever! Thanks! David thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the size_t* parameter was a pointer to a variable into which stoi places a position within the string after the end of the converted number.  i.e. it's an 'out' parameter, hence being a pointer.

For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404860.aspx

Perhaps you should point to the specific docs which are confusing.

Comment: [out] parameters in C++ are usually passed by reference, not pointer.

Comment: But this one is optional; it's legal to pass NULL. Which you can't do with a reference parameter.

Comment: @Sven: I was just pinpointing that the statement: "*it's an 'out' parameter, hence being a pointer*" is bogus. As I stated in another answer: *it's optional and hence a pointer*.

Comment: Since this is C++11 it should be noted the macro `NULL` should not be used. Instead use the `nullptr` type.