# Is std::stoi actually safe to use?

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer

I had a lovely conversation with someone about the downfalls of `std::stoi`. To put it bluntly, it uses `std::strtol` internally, and throws if that reports an error. According to them, though, `std::strtol` shouldn't report an error for an input of `"abcxyz"`, causing `stoi` not to throw `std::invalid_argument`.

First of all, here are two programs tested on GCC about the behaviours of these cases:
[strtol](http://ideone.com/6J6D7)
[stoi](http://ideone.com/dHBcd)

Both of them show success on `"123"` and failure on `"abc"`.

---

I looked in the standard to pull more info:

**§ 21.5**

```
Throws: invalid_argument if strtol, strtoul, strtoll, or strtoull reports that  
no conversion could be performed. Throws out_of_range if the converted value is  
outside the range of representable values for the return type.
```

That sums up the behaviour of relying on `strtol`. Now what about `strtol`? I found this in the C11 draft:

**§7.22.1.4**

```
If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no  
conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object  
pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.
```

Given the situation of passing in `"abc"`, the C standard dictates that `nptr`, which points to the beginning of the string, would be stored in `endptr`, the pointer passed in. This seems consistent with the test. Also, 0 should be returned, as stated by this:

**§7.22.1.4**

```
If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned.
```

The previous reference said that no conversion would be performed, so it must return 0. These conditions now comply with the C++11 standard for `stoi` throwing `std::invalid_argument`.

---

The result of this matters to me because I don't want to go around recommending `stoi` as a better alternative to other methods of string to int conversion, or using it myself as if it worked the way you'd expect, if it doesn't catch text as an invalid conversion.

So after all of this, did I go wrong somewhere? It seems to me that I have good proof of this exception being thrown. Is my proof valid, or is `std::stoi` not guaranteed to throw that exception when given `"abc"`?

Comment: If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; if no conversion is performed, an exception is thrown. Is there something else to prove?

Comment: @n.m., Well, I feel uneasy about basically going outright against the main point of their side. I've got the conversation here with them anonymous, but they were 30k rep, so I thought I might have misunderstood something along the way, as is often the case. Here's the log: http://i.imgur.com/KnHqH.png. If it turns out I didn't have a fault here, I'm sure I'll find some way to use my reinforced knowledge of the intricacies of this function later on ;)

Comment: The problem with `stoi` is that it succeeds on `"123abc"`, which means it's mostly useless unless you supply and check the ending-index parameter. This makes it even harder to use than `strtol` because you need to both check the end index, and catch the exception.

Comment: @interjay: *or* check the end index and *throw* an exception, if the index is wrong.

Comment: (fyi, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol has been updated.)

Comment: This makes `stoi` as useful as php string <-> integer conversion ;)

Comment: @interjay, Isn't that what you'd expect, though? If you were reading input like `cin >> someInt`, that's exactly what would happen. It seems like they kept user input in mind here, so that `cin >>someInt` is the same as `cin >> someString; someInt = stoi (someString);`. I'm sure there are other similarities throughout the language, as well. As explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407814/stoi-issue-with-design), if you keep this fact in mind, the end index parameter becomes useful.

Comment: I guess if that sort of case really is an issue for one, one can wrap the function with one that throws in that case as well.

Comment: @chris: I would expect it to throw an exception like `boost::lexical_cast` does. The most common use case is when you want to convert the entire string, and `stoi/l/ll` requires a bunch of boilerplate code to do that (or wrapping it in a function, which could also be done with `strtol`). The way `sto*` is implemented is more powerful, but doesn't really offer anything over `strto*`.

Comment: By the way, `cin >>someInt` is not the same as `cin >> someString; someInt = stoi (someString);`. In the case of input `123abc`, the first version will leave `abc` in the stream while the second will discard it silently.

Comment: @interjay, Yes, I see your point, especially if that's what boost does. By "same", I meant the result of the integer; I didn't concern the stream in the comparison.

Comment: James Kanze is a smart guy but smart guys make mistakes too.  Your mistake was that you forgot to censor his name one place in your screenshot.  His mistake is that he forgot that even though abcdef makes strtol return 0, strtol has to report the reason for returning 0 is that conversion fails, so stoi has to throw its exception.  But I'd still call stoi unsafe because of cases like 123abc.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer, I just noticed that before this comment and now I feel bad (I literally checked it 10 times) because the comment itself is part of this conversation >.> The 123abc case is what the real problem comes to, though, yes.

Comment: No need to feel bad.  EVERYONE makes mistakes.  If you want a good job then you don't admit your mistakes, you don't apologize for your mistakes, you end up on thedailywtf.com, and you keep your good job.  Anyway, no problem, James Kanze is a smart human, and being human, he occasionally makes mistakes too.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

### Does `std::stoi` throw an error on the input `"abcxyz"`?

Yes.

I think your confusion may come from the fact that `strtol` never reports *an error* except on overflow. It can report that no conversion was performed, but this is never referred to as an error condition in the C standard.

`strtol` is defined similarly by all three C standards, and I will spare you the boring details, but it basically defines a "subject sequence" that is a substring of the input string corresponding to the actual number. The following four conditions are equivalent:

- the subject sequence has the expected form (in plain English: it is a number)
- the subject sequence is non-empty
- a conversion has occurred
- `*endptr != nptr` (this only makes sense when `endptr` is non-null)

When there is an overflow, the conversion is still said to have occurred.

Now, it is quite clear that because `"abcxyz"` does not contain a number, the subject sequence of the string `"abcxyz"` must be empty, so that no conversion can be performed. The following C90/C99/C11 program will confirm it experimentally:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *nptr = "abcxyz", *endptr[1];
    strtol(nptr, endptr, 0);
    if (*endptr == nptr)
        printf("No conversion could be performed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This implies that any conformant implementation of `std::stoi` *must* throw `invalid_argument` when given the input `"abcxyz"` without an optional base argument.

---

### Does this mean that `std::stoi` has satisfactory error checking?

No. The person you were talking to is correct when she says that `std::stoi` is more lenient than performing the full check `errno == 0 && end != start && *end=='\0'` after `std::strtol`, because `std::stoi` silently strips away all characters starting from the first non-numeric character in the string.

In fact off the top of my head the only language whose native conversion behaves somewhat like `std::stoi` is Javascript, and even then you have to force base 10 with `parseInt(n, 10)` to avoid the special case of hexadecimal numbers:

```
input      |  std::atoi       std::stoi      Javascript      full check 
===========+=============================================================
hello      |  0               error          error(NaN)      error      
0xygen     |  0               0              error(NaN)      error      
0x42       |  0               0              66              error      
42x0       |  42              42             42              error      
42         |  42              42             42              42         
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------
languages  |  Perl, Ruby,     Javascript     Javascript      C#, Java,  
           |  PHP, C...       (base 10)                      Python...
```

*Note: there are also differences among languages in the handling of whitespace and redundant + signs.*

---

### Ok, so I want full error checking, what should I use?

I'm not aware of any built-in function that does this, but `boost::lexical_cast<int>` will do what you want. It is particularly strict since it even rejects surrounding whitespace, unlike Python's `int()` function. Note that invalid characters and overflows result in the same exception, `boost::bad_lexical_cast`.

```c
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string s = "42";
    try {
        int n = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
        std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;
    } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast) {
        std::cout << "conversion failed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: javascript actually considers `"0x42" == 66` true.

Comment: you _are_ having fun to build funny strings in your answer, aren't you? :)

Comment: Yeah, the == in Javascript performs type coersion before the compare, just in case someone reading this is wondering why.

Comment: Why is there std:atoi in the table with the language C? That should be a C++ i think..

Comment: I can't quite put a finger on why I have the feeling inside of me that a small piece of the puzzle is missing, but @GenericHuman, I would probably feel more relaxed and driven to accept this as a great answer if maybe there was a list of possibilities of what to do, e.g., how to implement the available choices into something that *will* give a reasonable error for those inputs that should. For one, I could wrap `stoi` in my own function that throws on not all characters being read, but is there a better option? What options do I have? Sorry that it *does* deviate from the original question.

Comment: @RedX: The equivalents to C++'s `std::atoi` are `int` in Perl, `.to_i` in Ruby, `(int)` in PHP and `atoi` in C. They all have different syntax but they all do the same thing.

Comment: @chris: Welcome to the wonderful world of C/C++'s standard library: there is *always* a small piece of the puzzle missing :-)

Comment: chris, to answer your new question, which deviates from the original question, you have to call strtol and check all of the information that it returns.  You've already been given that answer.  Of course you can roll your own replacement for strtol, but I think you don't have to go quite that far.  stoi should throw an exception on abcdef (your original question) but unfortunately not on 123abc (which was added later).

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer, Yes, I did see that flow in the comments. I was half keeping future visitors in mind when I posted my last comment, as it's much easier to find when it's laid out in an answer.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting that std::stoi has an optional second parameter via which the function reports the index of the first character in the input string that couldn't be converted? IMO this means the function does perform the full error check.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed, well written answer! Just a further comment on boost not accepting white-space. Could we mention that trimming the string first would be a good idea to parse a number as a string strictly? I think the idea from boost was to get out of the way, but ensure unexpected behaviours were not present in their library. In one way getting 32 out of "32 seymour street" could be good, so if you require that use `stoi`, but if you wanted to run some logic based upon a string being entirely numeric, use a library like boost, and ensure you supply separately sanitised strings.