# How can you check if something read in from a file is a valid integer?

Tags: c++

I'm trying something like:

```
int integer;

cin >> integer;

if(!integer) {//do something}
```

but obviously this is a problem if integer = 0.

Are there more efficient methods for checking if something is an integer?

Comment: If you get an integer directly, if that's what you get, it's an integer already and it's valid. If you get a text string, which may or may not contain a textual representation of an integer, then you can validate it, there are some functions in the standard library that can be used for the purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fail` or `operator bool` in `basic_ios` derived objects:

```
if(cin.fail()) {//do something}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::stoi()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). You'll get an exception if the string is not an integer value.

Comment: If you use `std::stoi`, you probably should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598990/is-stdstoi-actually-safe-to-use

Answer (score 0):

Please look up [fail bit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) - it will tell you something has gone amiss