# How to find values in a string and convert them to integers?

Tags: c++, string, int

My string is "I have 5 pencils and Tom have 3 pencils".
How I can find the values inside the string and then convert them into integers?

Answer (score 1):

You will need std::string and regex (std::regex does not work for now so use boost) to separate the numbers. Typical algorithm for you is:

1. Create boost::regex to separate the numbers.
2. Use boost::regex_search to obtain your numbers.
3. Use std::stoi to convert string to integer.

The sample code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("I have 5 pencils and Tom have 3 pencils");
  boost::smatch m;
  boost::regex e("[0-9]+");

  std::cout << "Target sequence: " << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Regular expression: /[0..9]+/" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "The following matches and submatches were found:" << std::endl;

  while (boost::regex_search (s, m, e))
  {
    for (auto x : m)
      std::cout << std::stoi(x) << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
  }

   return 0;
}
```

Simple Makefile to build that:

```
CC=g++
FLAGS=-std=c++11
LIBS=-lboost_regex

test: test.cpp
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIBS) test.cpp -o test
```

You should have either boost installed or use regex library of your choice.

Comment: Now we have to problems. Oh, and [stoi sucks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11599810/256138)

Comment: @rubenvb, yes, std::stoi sucks if you do not control the input. But since the input controlled by boost::regex or any other regex - you have nothing to fear. Also try {} catch () are still working. So catching an exception is not so hard, right?

Comment: @Tanuki, is there any other method that i can use other than regex?

Comment: @panadol, the regex is the easiest way to do that. If you'd like you can write your own tokenizer that will find numeric sequences. Something like:

for (auto c : search_string)
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') // This trick works good for ASCII
   // do something, process or accumulate;

Answer (score 0):

You could try tokenizing.

Create a Token and a Token_stream classes.

```
class Token
{
public:
    /* Implementation of the class */

private:
    char token_type;    // (e.g. store a letter such as 'a' for alphabetic
                        // characters and a number such as '8' for numbers)

    char letter;    // store which letter or ...
    int number;     // ... which number
}

class Token_stream
{
public:
    /* Implementation */

private:
    vector<Token> tokens;
}
```

Store every character contained in the string in one different Token and then store the Tokens into Token_stream. Then check every Token in the Token_stream to find out whether it's type is a number or an alphabetic character. If it is a number than just store it's value in a vector of ints, otherwise check the next Token in the stream.

OR

using a range-for loop, check every character stored in the string, if it is a number, store it in an int.

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);

vector<int> numbers;

for (char c : s)
{
    if (48 <= c && c <= 57)    // ASCII values for characters of numbers 48 == '0',
    {                          // 49 == '1', ..., 57 == '9'
        cin.putback(c);    // put c back into the standard input, so that you can 
                           // read it again as an int

        int n;
        cin >> n;

        numbers.push_back(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3194923, how can I store the value in a vector of ints?

Comment: i got it. but what is the function of int n?

Comment: panadol, the int n inside the range-for loop is there, so that you can read the representation of a number (which you put back into cin) as an actual integer. If you look just bellow int n, you can see you are reading the value from cin into n. got it ?