# Boost Spirit Qi validating input parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a very basic Boost Spirit Qi grammar to parse either IP port or IP port range, i.e. either `"6322"` or `"6322-6325"`.

The grammar looks like:

```
  template<class It>
  void init_port_rule(u16_rule<It>& port)
  {
    port = boost::spirit::qi::uint_parser<uint16_t, 10, 2, 5>();
    port.name("valid port range: (10, 65535)");
  }

  typedef boost::fusion::vector
    < std::uint16_t
    , boost::optional<std::uint16_t>
    > port_range_type
  ;

  template<class It>
  struct port_range_grammar
    : boost::spirit::qi::grammar
      < It
      , port_range_type()
      >
  {
    typedef typename port_range_grammar::base_type::sig_type signature;

    port_range_grammar()
      : port_range_grammar::base_type(start, "port_range")
    {
      init_port_rule(port);
      using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
      start = port > -(lit("-") > port);
    }

  private:
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<It, signature> start;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<It, std::uint16_t()> port;
  };
```

I am a bit stuck to define, that in a range `port1` must be less than `port2`. I think I have to use `eps` parser here, but do not seem to find the proper way to specify it. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: related questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/6431404/85371 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/30385909/85371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use semantic actions. You don't always need to attach them to an `eps` node, though. Here's what you'd get if you do:

```
port %= uint_parser<uint16_t, 10, 2, 5>() >> eps[ _pass = (_val>=10 && _val<=65535) ];
start = (port >> -('-' >> port)) >> eps(validate(_val));
```

Note that the one rule uses [Simple Form `eps`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/eps.html#spirit.qi.reference.auxiliary.eps.simple_form) with semantic action attached. This requires `operator%=` to [still invoke automatic attribute propagation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html#spirit.qi.reference.nonterminal.rule.expression_semantics).

The second instance uses the [Semantic Predicate form of `eps`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/eps.html#spirit.qi.reference.auxiliary.eps.semantic_predicate). The `validate` function needs to be a Phoenix Actor, I defined it like:

```
struct validations {
    bool operator()(PortRange const& range) const {
        if (range.end)
            return range.start<*range.end;
        return true;
    }
};
boost::phoenix::function<validations> validate;
```

### More Generic/Consistent

Note you can use the second rule style on both rules like so:

```
port %= uint_parser<Port, 10, 2, 5>() >> eps(validate(_val));
start = (port >> -('-' >> port))      >> eps(validate(_val));
```

if you simply add an overload to validate a single port:

```
struct validations {
    bool operator()(Port const& port) const {
        return port>=10 && port<=65535;
    }
    bool operator()(PortRange const& range) const {
        if (range.end)
            return range.start<*range.end;
        return true;
    }
};
```

### First Tests

Let's define some nice edge cases and test them!

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/284fa7a6e8e121ce)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using Port = std::uint16_t;

struct PortRange {
    Port start;
    boost::optional<Port> end;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(PortRange, start, end)

template <class It, typename Attr = PortRange> struct port_range_grammar : qi::grammar<It, Attr()> {

    port_range_grammar() : port_range_grammar::base_type(start, "port_range") {
        using namespace qi;

        port %= uint_parser<Port, 10, 2, 5>() >> eps(validate(_val));
        start = (port >> -('-' >> port))      >> eps(validate(_val));

        port.name("valid port range: (10, 65535)");
    }

  private:
    struct validations {
        bool operator()(Port const& port) const {
            return port>=10 && port<=65535;
        }
        bool operator()(PortRange const& range) const {
            if (range.end)
                return range.start<*range.end;
            return true;
        }
    };
    boost::phoenix::function<validations> validate;
    qi::rule<It, Attr()> start;
    qi::rule<It, Port()> port;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    port_range_grammar<It> const g;

    std::string const valid[]   = {"10", "6322", "6322-6325", "65535"};
    std::string const invalid[] = {"9", "09", "065535", "65536", "-1", "6325-6322"};

    std::cout << " -------- valid cases\n";
    for (std::string const input : valid) {
        It f=input.begin(), l = input.end();
        PortRange range;
        bool accepted = parse(f, l, g, range);
        if (accepted)
            std::cout << "Parsed '" << input << "' to " << boost::fusion::as_vector(range) << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "TEST FAILED '" << input << "'\n";
    }

    std::cout << " -------- invalid cases\n";
    for (std::string const input : invalid) {
        It f=input.begin(), l = input.end();
        PortRange range;
        bool accepted = parse(f, l, g, range);
        if (accepted)
            std::cout << "TEST FAILED '" << input << "' (returned " << boost::fusion::as_vector(range) << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
 -------- valid cases
Parsed '10' to (10 --)
Parsed '6322' to (6322 --)
Parsed '6322-6325' to (6322  6325)
Parsed '65535' to (65535 --)
 -------- invalid cases
TEST FAILED '065535' (returned (6553 --))
```

> ***CONGRATULATIONS*** We found a broken edge case

Turns out that by limiting uint_parser to 5 positions, we may leave characters in the input, so that `065535` parses as `6553` (leaving `'5'` unparsed...). Fixing that is simple:

```
start = (port >> -('-' >> port)) >> eoi >> eps(validate(_val));
```

Or indeed:

```
start %= (port >> -('-' >> port)) >> eoi[ _pass = validate(_val) ];
```

Fixed version **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c2d7b4f9f46f614)</kbd>**

### A Few Words About The Attribute Type

You will have noticed I revised your attribute type. Most of this is "good taste". Note, in practice you might want to represent your range as either single-port or range:

```
using Port = std::uint16_t;

struct PortRange {
    Port start, end;
};

using PortOrRange = boost::variant<Port, PortRange>;
```

Which you would then parse like:

```
port %= uint_parser<Port, 10, 2, 5>() >> eps(validate(_val));
range = (port >> '-' >> port)         >> eps(validate(_val));

start = (range | port) >> eoi;
```

Full demo **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c619d949049cfc5)</kbd>**

You might think this will get unweildy to use. ***I agree!***

### Simplify Instead

Let's do without `variant` or `optional` in the first place. Let's make a single port **just a range** which happens to have `start==end`:

```
using Port = std::uint16_t;

struct PortRange {
    Port start, end;
};
```

Parse it like:

```
start = port >> -('-' >> port | attr(0)) >> eoi >> eps(validate(_val));
```

All we do in `validate` is to check whether `end` is `0`:

```
    bool operator()(PortRange& range) const {
        if (range.end == 0) 
            range.end = range.start;
        return range.start <= range.end;
    }
```

And now the output is: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32afe975c4969f39)</kbd>**

```
 -------- valid cases
Parsed '10' to (10-10)
Parsed '6322' to (6322-6322)
Parsed '6322-6325' to (6322-6325)
Parsed '65535' to (65535-65535)
 -------- invalid cases
```

Note how you can now always enumerate `start`..`end` without knowing whether there was a port or a port-range. This may be convenient (depending a bit on the logic you're implementing).

Comment: Perhaps the most important take-away from this answer: never forget about _correctness_ (I do think the misparsing of `"065535"` is worse than any style issue. Although I think they are related. Making things easy to work with makes it easier to write tests; more time spent thinking of edge-cases and less effort fixing them.)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I've figured it out...

```
port_range_grammar()
  : port_range_grammar::base_type(start, "port_range")
{
  init_port_rule(port);
  using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
  namespace pnx = boost::phoenix;
  namespace fus = boost::fusion;
  start = port > -(lit("-") > port)
               > eps( pnx::bind
                       ( [](auto const& parsed)
                         {
                           if(!fus::at_c<1>(parsed).is_initialized())
                             return true;

                           auto lhs = fus::at_c<0>(parsed);
                           auto rhs = *fus::at_c<1>(parsed);
                           return lhs < rhs;
                         }
                       , _val
                       )
                    )
  ;
}
```

The idea is to pass the parsed value to the `eps` parser which is going to check if constructed `port_range_type` has first element lesser than the second element.

Comment: Wow. That's heroic. And... horrible :) I'm happy to inform you my answer lists ... about 6 different approaches that are less horrible.

Comment: Don't worry though, you have shown that you now understand the mechanics of semantic actions, phoenix actors, fusion sequences and semantic predicates. This hands-on experience is invaluable and could never be replaced by anything you learned from reading or copying form others. +1 from me

Comment: @sehe: Thanks for your great answer! This is definitely very insightful. I used  semantic actions before, my major difficulty was to understand what is going to be passed to `eps` parser. Either `_val` or `_1` or even `{_1, _2}`  :( Finally, I'd be thankful if you can explain, why my approach is considered be horrible (besides, that I use fusion::vector instead of hand-crafted type).

Comment: Let me see: Requiring a bind, requiring at_c, requiring magic indices with that, requiring hardcoding logic inside a parser expression in a way that makes it very hard to understand what is being tested (in fact, I don't think many people would even guess anything was being tested). Informally, though, you could ask random passers-by which code they would prefer reading :)

Comment: Don't take it too hard, I'm impressed you came up with this, like I said. I would **not** have upvoted this answer if I thought it was a bad idea. In fact, I think it might help others understand how it works, in much the way you found it out. Thanks for that contribution!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words and pointing out what can be improved :)